# PHP IP based location vs Geolocation

Tags: php, geolocation, location, ip

For PHP

1. What is the difference of IP based location and HTML5 Geolocation?
2. Which is more accurate?
3. Can we bypass user authorization for both without user consent?
4. Can I use VPN to fake my location to certain website? But what if the website is asking for my Geolocation therefore this is my concern too.

Comment: I need an solid answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HTML 5 is the newest standard set by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C). Prior to HTML 5, GeoLocation is done normally on the server side where a web visitor's IP address is captured and then matched against a geolocation database which will return more detailed information about that visitor's Country, State, City and a whole lot more.

With the announcement of the HTML 5 standard, it will now become easier to get those GeoLocation information on the client side. This is due to the fact that included inside the HTML 5 standard is a specification for a new JavaScript based GeoLocation API. Some of the newer browsers available today already support this new GeoLocation lookup which leverages data collected from Global Positioning System (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs, as well as user input.

Source: http://www.ipgeo5.com

2. HTML5 is generally more accurate.
3. No.
4. Yes for IP address. However, HTML5 provides more information such as MAC address which is not hidden by VPN.